# Why does copying a specific buffer size with memcpy and sprintf, prints more chars in new buffer than there are in the original buffer?

Tags: c, buffer

I have a general understanding question! Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
    // read user input
    char input[64] = {0};
    read(0, input, 64);
    printf("You've entered ");
    printf(input);

    char newbuf[128];
    char smallbuf[8];

    // copy into smallbuf 8 bytes of input
    memcpy(smallbuf, input, 8);

    // send smallbuf of 8 bytes as string into newbuf
    sprintf(newbuf, "%s", smallbuf);

    // print newbuf
    printf(&newbuf[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

The behavior I get with 7 chars is okay, it does print 7 chars:

```
$ gcc a.cpp -o a.out && ./a.out
1234567
You've entered 1234567
1234567
1234567
```

But with 8 chars it prints a lot more of them and I'm wondering why does it do this:

```
$ gcc a.cpp -o a.out && ./a.out 
12345678
You've entered 12345678
1234567812345678
```

Thank you for explaining me! :)

Comment: strings have null to mark the end.  If you don't copy the null the string is not terminated

Comment: @stark does this mean that if we write n-1 chars as input then, when we hit enter the termination null char is copied but when we write exactly n chars where n is the size of bytes to copy then we omit the termination null char because we overwrite it with the last char of input?

Comment: There is no terminating null character when you call `read`.  You've skirted that problem by initilizing your `input` array with all 0's, but then the problem rears its head when you write to `smallbuf` and `newbuf`.

Comment: Also, please never write things like `printf(&newbuf[0])`.  If the user happens to type a string containing a `%` sign or two, crazy things will happen!  Always print strings using `printf("%s", &newbuf[0])`, or `puts(&newbuf[0])`.  (And in this case you could get away with `printf("%s", newbuf)`, or `puts(newbuf)`. )

Comment: memcpy doesn't know about strings. Have a look at the string.h functions.

Comment: If this is C you should include string.h  cstring is for C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is attempting to print a character array as if it was a *string* leading to **undefined behavior**.
`smallbuf[]` does not certainly contain a *null character*, so it is not a *string*.
`"%s"` expects a matching pointer to a *string*.

Either account for a *null character*

```
char smallbuf[8+1];
memcpy(smallbuf, input, 8);
smallbuf[8] = '\0';
printf("%s", smallbuf);
```

or limit output with a *precision*.  That prints a character array up to N characters or a *null character*.

```
char smallbuf[8];
memcpy(smallbuf, input, 8);
printf("%.8s", smallbuf);
```

Similar issue applies to `printf(input);`

---

Do not code `printf(input);` as that may lead to *undefined behavior* when `input[]` contains a `%`.

```
// printf(input);
printf("%s", input);
```

---

Better code would examine the return value of `read(0, input, 64)`.